# MYSQL Join Query Multiple Tables displays duplicate results for some fields

Tags: php, mysql, join, duplicates

I'm joining tables in a mysql query and it is giving me duplicate results because on one of the tables there are 2 results.

Here is my query.

```
$query_order = "
SELECT sfo.entity_id, sfo.status, sfo.created_at, sfo.customer_firstname, sfo.customer_lastname, sfo.customer_email, sfo.subtotal, sfo.shipping_amount, sfo.tax_amount, sfo.grand_total, sfo.total_paid, sfo.total_due, sfo.total_item_count,
sfoa.address_type, sfoa.firstname, sfoa.lastname, sfoa.street, sfoa.city, sfoa.region, sfoa.postcode, sfoa.telephone, sfoa.country_id,
sfoi.product_id, sfoi.name, sfoi.sku, sfoi.qty_ordered, sfoi.price, sfoi.original_price, sfoi.row_total, sfoi.additional_data as additional_data1,
sfst.track_number, sfst.carrier_code, sfst.title,
sfop.additional_data as additional_data2, sfop.amount_paid, sfop.amount_ordered

FROM sales_flat_order sfo

JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoa
ON sfo.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id

JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi
ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id

JOIN sales_flat_shipment_track sfst
ON sfo.entity_id = sfst.order_id

JOIN sales_flat_order_payment sfop
ON sfo.entity_id = sfop.entity_id

WHERE sfo.increment_id = '" . $po . "'

LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

The `parent_id` of `sales_flat_order_address` has 2 results because one of them is the billing address and the other is shipping address. Both of those fields have same `parent_id` value which is what I'm joining the table on.

All tables are being joined with the same value from the `sales_flat_order sfo` which is the `entity_id` and is the primary key of that table.

How can I make sure the other tables only output the values from their fields once while making sure I still get both the billing and shipping address from `sales_flat_order_address` table?

I tried GROUP BY which does eliminate duplicates, but it also eliminates the shipping address from the `sales_flat_order_address` table.

Should I structure the query with sub-queries? I've done a lot of searching but so far I am not sure how to go about my particular situation.

**UPDATE 5/7/2016**

What I had to do in order to allow both billing and shipping address to display and without duplicating other fields from other joined tables I simply joined the address table twice so that the while loop only loops once instead of twice.

So I added this to my `SELECT`

```
sfoab.address_type as billing, sfoab.firstname as bfirst, sfoab.lastname as blast, sfoab.street as bstreet, sfoab.city as bcity, sfoab.region as bregion, sfoab.postcode as bzip, sfoab.telephone as btel, sfoab.country_id as bcountry,
sfoas.address_type as shipping, sfoas.firstname as sfirst, sfoas.lastname as slast, sfoas.street as sstreet, sfoas.city as scity, sfoas.region as sregion, sfoas.postcode as szip, sfoas.telephone as stel, sfoas.country_id as scountry,
```

Then I joined the address table twice

```
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoab
ON sfo.entity_id = sfoab.parent_id AND sfoab.address_type = 'billing'

LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoas
ON sfo.entity_id = sfoas.parent_id AND sfoas.address_type = 'shipping'
```

and then finally inside the while loop my variables

```
$billing = ucfirst($row['billing']);
$billing_firstname = $row['bfirst'];
$billing_lastname = $row['blast'];
$billing_name = ucwords($billing_firstname . " " . $billing_lastname);
$billing_street = ucwords($row['bstreet']);
$billing_city = ucwords($row['bcity']);
$billing_region = $row['bregion'];
$billing_postcode = $row['bzip'];
$billing_telephone = $row['btel'];
$billing_country = $countries[$row['bcountry']];

$shipping = ucfirst($row['shipping']);
$shipping_firstname = $row['sfirst'];
$shipping_lastname = $row['slast'];
$shipping_name = ucwords($shipping_firstname . " " . $shipping_lastname);
$shipping_street = ucwords($row['sstreet']);
$shipping_city = ucwords($row['scity']);
$shipping_region = $row['sregion'];
$shipping_postcode = $row['szip'];
$shipping_telephone = $row['stel'];
$shipping_country = $countries[$row['scountry']];
```

What others were suggesting was to use GROUP BY or DISTINCT. When I used those methods, it would not show both billing and shipping address. It would only show billing and not shipping address.

And when I left those methods off, both billing and shipping showed, but then it would cause other fields from other tables to be output twice.

So my only solution I found was to join the address table twice. Doing it this way I get what I want. And the while loop doesn't loop twice to get both address types.

If you know a better or more efficient way to accomplish this please let me know. I'm a newbie with MySQL queries and while loops.

Comment: use distinct to remove duplicate results

Comment: Distinct didn't remove dupes

Comment: Please read my UPDATE in the description above and let me know if my resolution is an appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try grouping by a Unique Column: like this?

```
<?php 
    //THE ONLY ADDITION HERE IS THE "GROUP BY" CLAUSE
    //OTHERWISE THIS IS YOUR OWN CODE WITH THE EXCEPTION OF FORMATTING...



        $query_order = "
            SELECT
            sfo.entity_id,
            sfo.status,
            sfo.created_at,
            sfo.customer_firstname,
            sfo.customer_lastname,
            sfo.customer_email,
            sfo.subtotal,
            sfo.shipping_amount,
            sfo.tax_amount,
            sfo.grand_total,
            sfo.total_paid,
            sfo.total_due,
            sfo.total_item_count,

            sfoa.address_type,
            sfoa.firstname,
            sfoa.lastname,
            sfoa.street,
            sfoa.city,
            sfoa.region,
            sfoa.postcode,
            sfoa.telephone,
            sfoa.country_id,

            sfoi.product_id,
            sfoi.name,
            sfoi.sku,
            sfoi.qty_ordered,
            sfoi.price,
            sfoi.original_price,
            sfoi.row_total,
            sfoi.additional_data as additional_data1,

            sfst.track_number,
            sfst.carrier_code,
            sfst.title,
            sfop.additional_data as additional_data2,
            sfop.amount_paid,
            sfop.amount_ordered



            FROM sales_flat_order_address sfoa,
                 sales_flat_order sfo



            JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi
            ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id

            JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi
            ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id

            JOIN sales_flat_shipment_track sfst
            ON sfo.entity_id = sfst.order_id

            LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_payment sfop
            ON sfo.entity_id = sfop.entity_id

            WHERE sfo.increment_id = " . (int)$po . "

            GROUP BY sfo.entity_id

            LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

Depending on what you want to achieve; a LEFT JOIN may come in handy like so:

```
$query_order = "
    SELECT
    sfo.entity_id,
    sfo.status,
    sfo.created_at,
    sfo.customer_firstname,
    sfo.customer_lastname,
    sfo.customer_email,
    sfo.subtotal,
    sfo.shipping_amount,
    sfo.tax_amount,
    sfo.grand_total,
    sfo.total_paid,
    sfo.total_due,
    sfo.total_item_count,

    sfoa.address_type,
    sfoa.firstname,
    sfoa.lastname,
    sfoa.street,
    sfoa.city,
    sfoa.region,
    sfoa.postcode,
    sfoa.telephone,
    sfoa.country_id,

    sfoi.product_id,
    sfoi.name,
    sfoi.sku,
    sfoi.qty_ordered,
    sfoi.price,
    sfoi.original_price,
    sfoi.row_total,
    sfoi.additional_data as additional_data1,

    sfst.track_number,
    sfst.carrier_code,
    sfst.title,
    sfop.additional_data as additional_data2,
    sfop.amount_paid,
    sfop.amount_ordered


    FROM sales_flat_order_address sfoa,
    sales_flat_order sfo                     


    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi
    ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id

    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_shipment_track sfst
    ON sfo.entity_id = sfst.order_id

    LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_payment sfop
    ON sfo.entity_id = sfop.entity_id

    WHERE sfo.increment_id = " . (int)$po . "

    GROUP BY sfo.entity_id

    LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

I hope this helps in a bit...

Comment: I had already tried this and yes it removes duplicates but it also removes the shipping address in the `sales_flat_order_address` table. How can I still get both values from that table? The shipping and billing address which are duplicate values on the `parent_id` of that table.

Comment: Oh, Yes... you are right... I just updated the Query... would you mind re-trying it... ?

Comment: That also still removes shipping address and leaves only billing address.

Comment: Please read my UPDATE in the description above and let me know if my resolution is an appropriate one.